# When do companies usually release flights?

Tags: air-travel

So I am going away next May (May 2017) to Cyprus and booked the hotel as I got it at a really good price.

I then searched for flights and found there to be just one, which was leaving at major airports within the UK. This, however, does not suit me as the flight times are really bad. The other options include multiple flights but these are around (£1000+) whereas a direct flight will cost around (£500).

Am I right in thinking that closer to the time, airlines will release more flights to this destination? Do I need to panic and maybe cancel the hotel?

Comment: kindly tell me your preferred departure and arrival airports

Comment: Airlines release flights and change schedules all the time. Looking at next May from LON-LCA I see various non-stop flights on Norwegian and BA for < £200 though.

Comment: @Newton (MAN -> Paphos International Airport) May 9th - May 16th

Comment: @Newton Or can be any London*

Comment: I suspect you're looking around dates in late May around the Spring Bank Holiday. BA have only high price fares for those dates, but lower price fares both earlier in May and in June

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On average airlines open flights for bookings around 330 days prior, so May dates may not yet be open depending on the airline and route.

You can test route options by simply looking at earlier dates (say March or April) just to see if many more options show.  While it is not a guarantee, it does give you a starting point.

Comment: Next May is way more than 330 days. BA only seem to have H fares in late May though

Comment: Actually May is less than 330 days in the future, but not every airline opens dates that far ahead.

Comment: Sorry, I meant way less than 330 days.

Comment: BA first opens seats 355 days into the future, at about 1 am UK time. However, they may not open the discount fare buckets for a week or so after that.

Comment: @Calchas - As I said on average, BA does is further, some airlines do it closer.  But based on that all BA options should be showing for May. The OP will have hope some other airline offers something.